# Issues with Google analytics iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I know that there are a lot of questions and answers about google analytics issues, but nothing helps me.

I have installed google with pods

pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

and imported this in bridging header, and use this code in appDelegate

```
<GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>
"GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
            assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
        }

        GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker = gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "UA-109196643-1")
        // Optional: automatically report uncaught exceptions.
        gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true
        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatch { (result) in
            print(result)
        }
        // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
        // Remove before app release.
        gai.logger.logLevel = .verbose;
```

here is the logging text

> INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch]
>   (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:369): No pending hits. INFO: GoogleAnalytics
>   3.17 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:161): Reachability flags update: 0X000002

and here is the log when I am logging screen

> GoogleAnalytics 3.17 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:]
>   (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:518): Saved hit: {
>       parameters =     {
>           "&_crc" = 0;
>           "&_s" = 9;
>           "&_u" = ".npetoK9L";
>           "&_v" = "mi3.1.7";
>           "&a" = 1028296819;
>           "&aid" = "******";
>           "&an" = Mataam;
>           "&av" = "1.0";
>           "&cid" = "59cc9c6e-be21-4ac8-b6d9-d3beff894dbf";
>           "&dm" = "x86_64";
>           "&ds" = app;
>           "&sr" = 1242x2208;
>           "&t" = screenview;
>           "&tid" = "UA-109196643-1";
>           "&ul" = en;
>           "&v" = 1;
>           "&z" = 15726875618543142345;
>           Login = name;
>           gaiVersion = "3.17";
>       };
>       timestamp = "2017-11-11 15:42:53 +0000"; }

So the problem is that I dont get any data in analytics, I have also setup firebase, can it be the issue, because I am getting data there.

Comment: I think something wrong in your code.

Comment: You already created instance of GAI.sharedInstance() named as gai. So, use gai or GAI.sharedInstance(), why are you use both ?

Comment: Firebase gives great analytics... Why do you need Google Analytics?

Comment: Thanks @Yitzchak, I completely agree with you, but the client wants google one )

Comment: Firebase is google too and can be linked to google analytics!!!

Comment: yes I know that firebase is also owned by google, so how can I link it, and when client will enter https://analytics.google.com, will see any data?

Comment: Finally I have linked it, thanks mate )

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a new answer because it's my answer and I add more details:

You can use Firebase SDK and get analytics in your Google Analytics account.
You just link them together.

Follow the instructions:

[Link to instructions on Google Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en)

> 1. Sign in to your Google Analytics account.
> 2. Click Admin.
> 3. In the PROPERTY column, select Create new property from the dropdown menu.
> 4. Select Mobile app.
> 5. Connect to Firebase.
>      If you do not have a Firebase account, go to firebase.google.com to get started. Once you have completed the setup, return to Google Analytics and complete the above steps.

Comment: )) yes its your answer, but as you can see I didnt pick my answer as correct, because its doesnt fix the issue which I wrote in my post, so I guess it will not be correct if I pick this as accepted answer, btw thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

My code still doesnt work, but I have found how to link firebase analytics to google analytics(thanks @Yitzchak).
When you are adding property for mobile app you can link it to firebase, and it will automatically import data from firebase.